# How soon can my Colombian partner come to the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

I want my Colombian partener to come and live with me in the UK, we're not married but she is pregnant with my child, I need here here ASAP as I'm 100% she's the one.

Any chance she can come here before applying for long term visa/citizenship? As I know that Colombians no longer need Visa to come as a tourist. I work full time on good pay, I'm English with an English passport. How hard is the government going to make it so my partner carrying a child from someone English can live with me so we can start our family?

Comment: Note the recently announced [increase in immigration fees](https://freemovement.org.uk/massive-increases-to-immigration-fees-announced/).  The annual NHS surcharge is going up from £624 to £1,035.  This is in addition to thousands of pounds in visa and residence permit fees.  I hope your pay is good indeed.

Comment: The route for partners/family is described [here](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa) and to citizenship [here](https://www.gov.uk/british-citizenship). First of all, you need to figure out if you & your partner even meet the criteria to apply for a family visa.

Comment: FWIW, no such thing as an English passport - only a British/UK one.

The only legal way for her to live in the UK will be with an approriate visa.

Comment: It would almost certainly be easier for you to go to Spain and start your family there.

Comment: Since you mention visa-free entry as a visitor for Colombian citizens, reading [Pregnancy during visa application or stay in the UK](https://immigrationlawyers-london.com/blog/pregnancy-during-visa-application-or-stay-in-the-uk.php) might help. Also consider the likely costs should your partner need ante natal care / give birth while in the UK as a visitor [NHS maternity care for women from abroad](https://maternityaction.org.uk/advice/nhs-maternity-care-for-women-from-abroad-in-england/)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have already married [Otis Solicitors](https://www.otssolicitors.co.uk/news/does-marriage-to-a-british-citizen-give-you-the-right-to-live-in-the-uk/) says

> **Relationships and the right to reside in the UK**
>
> Your relationship does not give you the right to reside in the UK, however long you have been married and however committed you are to your partner. Some couples struggle with that statement, assuming that British citizens have the right to live with whomever they want in their home country. Whilst a British citizen (or a person with settled status) does have a right to reside, the law says that their husband, wife, civil partner, or partner doesn’t have an automatic right if they are subject to UK immigration controls.
>
> There is a route to UK entry clearance based on your relationship, namely the spouse visa or family visa. However, a marriage certificate or evidence of a relationship isn’t sufficient to secure a spouse visa or partner visa – you have to meet all the eligibility criteria to obtain a spouse visa.
> . . .
> The route to British citizenship from marriage is quite long and can be complicated depending on your circumstances. Not everyone who marries and comes to live in the UK decides to apply for British citizenship as some think that indefinite leave to remain status is sufficient as it gives them the right to live and work in the UK on an indefinite basis.

On top of that you are not yet married, and (with respect to you and your partner) is there proof that you are the father? There are many, many people who have fallen victim to "visa romances" and I hope you are not one of them. The bottom line is that your feelings for your partner have nothing to do with obtaining residency.

Not needing a visa, isn't the same thing as "not subject to immigration controls".

Comment: I get what you mean about a visa romance but she lives in spain and so was i when we met, we were already in a relationship before i left spain to come back to the uk for work and then the pregnancy happened as i left but had already made the choice of long distance

Comment: I think you would be wise to reckon up the total time you have spent with your partner, and perhaps ask your friends whether 3/6/9/12 etc months are enough to get to know someone well enough to be serious about marriage.

Comment: @LeonParsons The UK rule is that the relationship must have lasted more than 2 years at time of application

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Actually IIRC the rule is that the applicant and their partner must have been *living together in a relationship for at least 2 years when you apply*

Comment: @Traveller Exactly yes

Comment: "Living together" is not the same as "in a relationship", especially since OP and partner are currently living in different countries.